# Combining HTML, CSS, and JS into one HTML file (Creating a Bell Curve Using Google Charts API)

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I'd like to combine the HTML, CSS, and JS into a single HTML script for the code already created at "Bell Curve Using Google Charts API"

https://codepen.io/josdea/pen/JKXpJb/

It should be as simple as putting the CSS in style and JS in script in the head, right?  For some reason, I can't get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"     
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var data;
var options;
let chart;
var stndDev = 1;
var mean = 0;
let xMin = -3;
let xMax = 3.1;
let xLeft = -2;
let xRight = 1.25;

google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(prepareChart);

function prepareChart() {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  setChartOptions();
  addColumns();
  addData();
  drawChart();
}
function setChartOptions() {
  options = { legend: "none" };
  options.hAxis = {};
  options.hAxis.minorGridlines = {};
  options.hAxis.minorGridlines.count = 5;
  return options;
}
function addColumns() {
  data.addColumn("number", "X Value");
  data.addColumn("number", "Y Value");
  data.addColumn({ type: "boolean", role: "scope" });
  data.addColumn({ type: "string", role: "style" });
}
function addData() {
  data.addRows(createArray(xMin, xMax, xLeft, xRight, mean, stndDev));
}
function createArray(xMin, xMax, xLeft, xRight, mean, stndDev) {
  let chartData = new Array([]);
  let index = 0;
  for (var i = xMin; i <= xMax; i += 0.1) {
    chartData[index] = new Array(4);
    chartData[index][0] = i;
    chartData[index][1] = jStat.normal.pdf(i, mean, stndDev);

    if (i < xLeft || i > xRight) {
      chartData[index][2] = false;
    }
    chartData[index][3] =
      "opacity: 1; + color: #8064A2; + stroke-color: black; ";

    index++;
  }
  return chartData;
}
function drawChart() {
  chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(
    document.getElementById("chart_div")
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <style>
#chart_div{
width: 1200px;
height: 600px;
margin: 5px;
}
  </style>


    <h1>Bell Curve with Google Charts API</h1>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The code currently results in a "Data Table Not Defined" Error.

Comment: I'm receiving a console error that `jStat` is undefined. What are you expecting to load that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the console errors (instructions for [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)), you'll see "jStat", a 3rd party library your JS requires, is not defined.

```
test.html:50 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: jStat is not defined
at createArray (test.html:50)
at addData (test.html:42)
at prepareChart (test.html:25)
```

CodePen is conveniently hiding the additional JS include under "Settings". You need to explicitly add the script to your HTML file. Add this tag before the `loader.js` `<script>` line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstat/1.7.0/jstat.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help mac9416!   You rock!

Answer (score 1):

> Please add these references in same sequence and it will work for you, there is no problem with your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstat/1.7.0/jstat.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Output screen:
[image]